# PHP - used __construct() to check if there is a session

Tags: php, session

I have a class that has multiple related queries to the database with user data, to access these methods need to verify that the user is logged in, and I do it using php initializer "__construct ()" methods, specify there if the user logged on.

```
<?php
class User() 
{
    public function __construct() {

        if ( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
            $data = array(
                'response' => false,
                'message'   => 'You must login to access this page'.
            );
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        // The user can access if you are logged
    }

    public function edit_profile()  {
        // The user can not access if you have not logged
    }

    public function save_profile_data() {
        // The user can not access if you have not logged
    }
}
?>
```

**My questions:**

1. Use the **__construct()** is a good optimal choice resource-intensive?
2. The **__construct()** is safe to use and prevent the user to access other methods that have not specified whether there is coded session variable.

Ie if a user calls the **edit_profile()** method, and this method does not have the code to check for the session, but I have specified in the **__construct()**, the user can access this method?

Comment: Looks like you are just beginning with PHP here. OK, probably the best approach is to declare a `private` property in the class that sets a flag for permission on method execution. Then inside each method, you ask for this flag's state to see if you are allowed to execute or not.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: @MarkSkayff - Thank you for your answer, but if you see something a little technical in a matter of usability, because what I want is not to generate much code in other methods, so we have specified in the __construct ()

Comment: have a base class that redirects upon entry point, since all the methods in `User` need to make sure there logged in, better to hide those details.

Comment: @Learningandsharing Well, you can handle whatever you want in the construct, and if the user is not logged in you can handle some action (say a redirection) outside of that class or in that same constructor, making the user know he must login to proceed. Otherwise, you should be treating this permission in a per method basis.

Comment: @RichardTheobald I see that spelled correctly.

Comment: @MarkSkayff It was corrected in the second edit.

Comment: @MarkSkayff The entire purpose of class's constructor is to initialize a state (i.e injecting dependencies). It's a bad practice to perform calculations there both for testing and debugging.

Comment: What is the most effective recommendation, specified in the constructor or the session separated by methods do? Assuming you have the code to check a sample session: check_if_loggin (), I call this in the constructor or do it separately for each method and if so, what are the advantages or contra of doing it this way.

Comment: That's pretty long to write. Instead look how this is done, for example in Laravel/Zend

Comment: I searched a lot of information, I have seen many examples, but they do and do not explain why, I try to know that, which certainly gives me a forum I found a comment that the constructor resource intensive. As we know the constructor initializes charging the web, but it is a good development practice? it can cause a problem or security breach? For methods that do not have the code to verify that there is a session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to create your own library file in library folder
Here is the class file

```
class Authenticate {
    var $table;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();

    }
  public function is_logged_in()
    {
        $sessionid = $this->ci->session->userdata('moderId');
        if($sessionid)
        {
        return isset($sessionid);
        }
         else if(!$sessionid) {
      redirect(base_url() . 'moderator');
 }
    }
}
```

And in your controller,use this function.if you put this function in the constructor of the controller,then it wil be available to all methods
Controller

```
class B2bcategory extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('moderator/b2bcategory_model');

        $this->authenticate->is_logged_in();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent @Angel, thank you very much, it is understood, we can use the builder to check for a meeting, thank you for your support that you have a happy day.

Comment: Thank you so much for very nice compliment for me... i am very happy to help people. Have a nice day to you too